# Non-exhaustive patterns in function checkStr when counting number of nondigits in string

Tags: haskell

I made a program that is counting number of nondigits in string. It returns value based on how many nondigits were found. When I run my code Ghci says that " Non-exhaustive patterns in function checkStr". What's the problem?

```
checkStr:: String -> Int

digits = ['0'..'9']

checkStr_ _ [] = 0

checkStr (str:ss)
   | str `elem` digits = checkStr ss
   | otherwise = 1 + checkStr ss
```

Comment: Why are there two underscores here?

Comment: Compile with warnings. `:set -Wall` in ghci

Answer (score 2):

You here defined two functions `checkStr_` and `checkStr`. The last one only covers the patter `(str:ss)`. So eventually the list will be exhausted, and the it will be called with `[]`. You do not have any logic for that.

You can implement this with:

```
checkStr :: String -> Int
checkStr [] = 0
checkStr (str:ss)
   | str `elem` digits = checkStr ss
   | otherwise = 1 + checkStr ss
```

That being said, we can make the above by `filter`ing on the `isDigit` function, and then calculate the length:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit)

checkStr :: String -> Int
checkStr = length . filter (not . isDigit)
```